# windows 10 IOT electron app support

Tags: electron, windows-10-iot-core

I don't know can I ask a simple answer here?

Can Windows 10 IOT support electron app build with nodejs and javascript/typescript?

Somewhere I read it support Linux ARM, but how about Windows 10 IOT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm fairly sure the answer is no.

For Windows 10 IoT you'll need to develop apps using the Universal Windows Platform SDK.

I'll delete this answer if we find out otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I have been looking for an answer to this question for some time and mostly all explorations have led me to pages where the "fairly sure answer is no" is the usual response due to reasons blah blah.

Strangely enough, according to this post (and quite an old one):

**Compiling Electron Apps for the Windows Store**
https://www.microsoft.com/developerblog/2016/05/08/compiling-electron-apps-for-the-windows-store/

You can pack your electron app and use it on Windows IoT.

Will do some packing and update if any of this works.

Comment: Note that the capability of being packaged into an AppX file does not necessarily mean that it will run on Windows 10 IoT Core.  Windows 10 IoT Enterprise will run anything compiles for the platform it runs on.

Comment: Actually I think I overlooked that part. Most likely it won't run on IoT core. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can run ARM apps on Windows IOT that are not UWP applications (sort of, but probably not supported yet):

Make a web app and do this:
https://carlos.mendible.com/2017/03/21/step-by-step-running-aspnet-core-on-raspberry-pi/

Then, make a UWP app with a web view to the app you just made:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/web-view